# TypeScript definition for createReadStream won't accept {start: 90, end: 99 } in the options

Tags: node.js, stream, typescript

I just updated to TypeScript 1.6.2 and my call to createReadStream() won't compile because the type definition in node.d.ts does not expect 'start' and 'end' in the options parameter.

```
 var st = fs.createReadStream(logFile , {start: rstart, end: rend } );
```

will get this error:

```
 error TS2345: Argument of type '{ start: number; end: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ flags?: string; encoding?: string; fd?: string; mode?: string; bufferSize?: number; }'.
```

Since the documentation does mention these as valid options (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) 
I do believe the node.d.ts should be fixed and I can issue a pull request with the fix, 
but - in the meantime - is there a way to force this call to pass the compiler?

thanks

Comment: Yeah, this looks like it should be fixed. Also, this line doesn't seem to be implemented in `node.d.ts`: `If options is a string, then it specifies the encoding.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do believe the node.d.ts should be fixed and I can issue a pull request with the fix, but - in the meantime - is there a way to force this call to pass the compiler?

You can assert it as `any` for now:

```
var st = fs.createReadStream(logFile, {start: rstart, end: rend } as any);
```

Or manually update your local `node.d.ts` to include those properties.